# Define a cell reference by calling part of it from another cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to change the referenced array of a cell without changing anything in the cell itself. For example:

```
=AVERAGE(D"5":D"500")
```

Where I am trying to average values in column 'D' from row 5 to row 500. But I want to call in the `5` and the `500` from other cells that are readily visible and changeable, without editing the function.

I have looked into several different functions including INDIRECT, CONCATENATE, INDEX, ADDRESS, and the `&` operator, but I cannot get any of them to return what I want.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems requirement is met with:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("D"&A1&":D"&B1))
```

Where the variables (`5` and `500`) are in cells A1 and B1 respectively.